# Cohomology of the complement of an elliptic arrangement

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the paper "*Cohomology of the complement of an elliptic arrangement*", the authors (Levin and Varchenko) consider the complement to an arrangement of (elliptic) hyperplanes in a cartesian
power of an elliptic curve and describe its cohomology with coefficients in a non-trivial rank
one local system (Actually, their result concerns generic rank one local systems).

What about the case of the trivial rank one local system $\mathbb C$?

I'm mainly interested in the case of the square of an elliptic curve.
Maybe this is already known. In this case, a good reference would be welcome

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

The following preprint of Christin Bibby seems to solve your problem completely: http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4866

Comment: Well, it gives an explicit cdga model for the complement of an elliptic arrangement, under a certain unimodularity assumption.  But this does not automatically yield a closed formula (say, generators and relators) for the cohomology ring of the complement...